# Integrate Server into Windows

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Is it possible to add my own server to my devices? I'm using Windows Vista and it should look like this:

[image]

If click on "Server (D:)" it should connect to the server and open its harddisk and show me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your server supports SMB shares (standard Windows file sharing) you can map a drive letter to a network share.  You do this by:

1. Open **My Computer**
2. On Windows XP select **Tools**->**Map a Network Drive** on Windows Vista/Windows 7, select **Map network drive** from the menu at the top of the screen.
3. Choose the drive letter and enter the path to the server in the dialog.

[image]

You can also find instructions on Microsoft's site:

- [Windows Vista/7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Create-a-shortcut-to-map-a-network-drive)
- [Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/maintain/mapdrive.mspx)

Comment: +1, what I would of wrote - but also, not just limited to Windows - you can always install Samba on Linux

Comment: The same method works for WebDAV too, not just SMB.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if you are asking how to [map a drive](http://askville.amazon.com/map-network-drive-Windows-Vista-make-remember-username-password-enter/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=2347107).  You can try [this link](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-map-a-drive-in-windows/) also.